# Get program that is stuck under task bar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a program that is stuck under the task bar in Windows 7.  I cannot click on it because (I think) the click is interpreted as being on the task bar and not on the program.

How do I recover it?  The program does not show up when I alt-tab through all of the programs.  It also does not show up in Applications in the Task Manager.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right-click on the Taskbar and select **Autohide**.

Comment: That is not an option.  I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Comment: I had to go to properties first -- I found the autohide option there.

Comment: yea this trick has saved me a few times!

Comment: I've also found if you resize the taskbar (eg make it one stop bigger) then all the program windows are moved accordingly so they arent underneath. This happens alot because I have my taskbar at the top, where many programs open

Answer (score 7):

Just click the taskbar and click on "Cascade Windows" or "Show Windows side by side". The window that has gone under the taskbar will snap back up!

Comment: I think the program might have crashed if it doesn't show up under Applications in the Task Manager, and if it can't be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>ed back into place.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the taskbar and unlock it if it is locked. then you can drag it out of the way and move the program.

Answer (score 2):

Browse to your Desktop folder in Windows Explorer (Windows logo + E)

(If you have the default UI, you're favorite folders should be on the top left. Desktop should be the first option.)

- Select the application shortcut in Explorer.
- Cut the shortcut and paste it somewhere (to remove it from your Desktop folder) and cut it again.
- Go to your Desktop (Windows logo + D) and paste it where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the programs Window (hover over program symbol, wait, right click the popping up window), hit "move" and use your arrows on the keyboard to move it up

Comment: I think you need to select the program to be the active window first.

Answer (score 2):

For most programs you can just tile and they'll be moved up for you.

If you're running Windows7 or higher you should be able to simply alt+tab or alt+windows+tab the program into focus and then windows+arrow the program around the screen.

Comment: +1 This answer is the only one to provide a 1-step solution.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone is having this issue on windows 10, right click on task bar, select properties, change "taskbar location on screen" to right or left....this should allow you to grab the hidden window. when your done you can just change it back

Answer (score -1):

Find the applications icon in your start menu, right click there and unpin from taskbar

Comment: I think the OP means the app window is stuck *behind* the task bar *not in* the task bar, so unpinning it is not a solution because in the first place it is not *pinned* to the task bar.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the Windows home button, then search taskbar. There will be an option called Autohide taskbar. Click on it. It will open a setting page. Check the box that says autohide taskbar. Then click apply.